# Editing a "partial" answer to be more complete

Tags: discussion, answers, edits

Please see my question on Stack Overflow: [Get Parent Value Using Nodes() and Value()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434728/get-parent-value-using-nodes-and-value).

Rafael Cordones Marcos answered with something that was partially correct in respect to my question; he provided the XQuery that allowed me to arrive at the SQL code I was looking for. As you can see, I added the final query I used simply so that it was available for others to see how I incorporated it into his suggestion.

**Is it acceptable for an asking member to edit another member's answer?** I didn't want to post my own answer since truly the "hard" part of the question was already solved. Still, I felt it was important to the question. I'm worried other members might feel slighted. Granted, this question didn't receive a ton of attention but I believe the point is still valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not edit an answer, if you are going to change its meaning.

The "how to edit" block that is visible to who doesn't have the privilege of editing every post, reports the following points:

- fix grammatical or spelling errors
- clarify meaning **without changing it**
- correct minor mistakes
- add related resources or links
- always respect the original author

In your case, you would change the meaning of the answer because you would add something the OP of the answer didn't write. If you were adding in the answer something that the OP wrote as comment, then that would be different; still, I would let the OP add that to his/her answer. (Suggesting the OP to include what reported in a comment as part of the answer is fine.)

It makes more sense to write your own answer, reporting that your answer has been inspired by the answer given from the other user.

Comment: Hmm... I did consider doing that (writing my own answer and crediting the inspiration for it), but felt it would border on begging for up-votes.

Comment: If you think it would border on begging for up-votes, you can make your answer a community wiki; in that way, you would not gain reputation from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I'd say it doesn't matter, because it just summarizes his answer. However if it wouldn't be part of his answer (another solution ...), it should be posted as separated one.

In any case, he/she can always rollback his/her changes to his last version if he's/she's not OK with changes

Comment: +1 And to clarify, I asked the question and then edited someone's answer to be more "useful" given what I was looking for.

Comment: @Yuck: oh, didn't notice you're asker.